# Force open ms word file in msword on client system

Tags: php

I have a msword file which is sitting on server.

i want when user tried of open it will open on his computer in msword **directly**.

```
<?php
$document ='MyWordDocument.docx';

/**Function to extract text*/
function extracttext($filename) 
{
    //Check for extension
    $ext = end(explode('.', $filename));

    //if its docx file
    if($ext == 'docx')
        $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
    //else it must be odt file
    else
        $dataFile = "content.xml";     

    //Create a new ZIP archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    // Open the archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
        // If successful, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // Index found! Now read it to a string
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Load XML from a string
            // Ignore errors and warnings
            $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            // Remove XML formatting tags and return the text
            return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
        }
        //Close the archive file
        $zip->close();
    }

    // In case of failure return a message
    return "File not found";
}

echo extracttext($document);
```

I tried above code but this code reads and display the content in browser. 
Can we achieve this using PHP?

Comment: this is beyond you control. Even if you stop it from displaying the content in the browser (which presumably is being done using a Word plugin, so it basically  _is_ Word, just with some of the toolbars hidden), the file will simply be offered for download. You can't force the user to download it, and if they do, you can't force them to open it. Think of the security risks if a browser could force-download and open random files onto your disk, viruses would be everywhere. The solution you've got now is actually probably the most user-friendly.

Comment: N.B. Any user whose browser doesn't have a compatible plugin installed for displaying Word files is probably getting a download prompt already instead of it displaying automatically. Some browsers e.g. Chrome can also be set to auto-download any files that are offered. Maybe you can even set it to open them too, I don't know. But this is all at each individual user's discretion, because it's their security which is at risk. Your server-side code has no say in what happens to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you can achieve is to download* the file into users computer. It is impossible to force him to also open the file. Why? Security.

*or display download dialog, depends on browser and settings.